# Clickable Header Image Missing Text

Tags: html, image, header, tags, anchor

My website has a header image that is also a link to the Home Page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="~/Default.aspx" runat="server" id="homelink"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
position: relative;
height: 150px;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0px auto;
background-image: url("../Styles/Images/Header.jpg"); /*--ZaraA (2014)--*/
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#homelink {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 1000px;
height: 150px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
float: left;
}
```

This is a university assignment so my pages must be as accessible as possible. The above fails accessibility checkers because there is no text inside the anchor tag.

How do I add some text inside the tag but have it not visible whilst making sure that the whole header image is still clickable back to the Home Page. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tekst to your anchor tag. Then add the following CSS:

```
#homelink {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will 'push' the text out of the visible part of the element. 
So it will be:

```
#homelink {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```